# TypeError: options.getMember is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, command

so I have been coding the ban command, just finished it and I started getting this error. I have no idea how to fix it even though searching through the internet for a while now. Can someone help me with this one?

This is the error I am getting:

```
/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/Commands/Moderation/ban.js:45
        const Target = options.getMember("target");
                               ^

TypeError: options.getMember is not a function
    at Object.execute (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/Commands/Moderation/ban.js:45:32)
    at Object.execute (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/Events/Interaction/interactionCreate.js:21:21)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/Structures/Handlers/Events.js:18:54)
    at Client.emit (node:events:538:35)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/InteractionCreate.js:74:12)
    at Object.module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:351:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/Users/Aplex/Documents/Aplel/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:199:18)
```

Here is my code, I would really appreciate it if someone told me what the issue here is, thank you so much.

```
const { Client, CommandInteraction, MessageEmbed} = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "ban",
    description: "Bans the target member",
    permission: "ADMINISTRATOR",
    options: [
        {
            name: "target",
            description: "Select a target to ban.",
            type: "USER",
            required: true,
        },
        {
            name: "reason",
            description: "Provide a reason for this ban.",
            type: "STRING",
            required: true,
        },
        {
            name: "messages",
            description: "Choose one of the choices.",
            type: "STRING",
            required: true,
            choices: [
                {
                    name: "Don't delete any",
                    value: "0"
                },
                {
                    name: "Previous 7 days.",
                    value: "7"
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
    /**
     * 
     * @param {Client} client 
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction 
     */
    async execute(client, interaction){
        const { options, member } = interaction;

        const Target = options.getMember("target");

        if(Target.id === member.id)
        return interaction.reply({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("RED").setDescription(`⛔ | You can't ban yourself.`)]})

        if(Target.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR"))
        return interaction.reply({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("RED").setDescription(`⛔ | You can't an administrator.`)]})

        const Reason = options.getString("reason");

        if(Reason.length > 512)
        return interaction.reply({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("RED").setDescription(`⛔ | The reason can't exceed 512 characters.`)]})

        const Amount = options.getString("messages")

        Target.ban({days: Amount, reason: Reason})

        interaction.reply({embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor("GREEN").setDescription(`✅ | **${target.user.username}** has been banned from the server.`)]})
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you include your code? Only seeing the error it's hard to help.

Comment: Oh my bad I thought I included it lol, yeah hold on

Answer (score 0):

To ban a user from guild you can use:

```js
const user = interaction.options.getUser('target');
```

whereas to kick a user you can use:

```js
const member = interaction.options.getMember('target');
member.kick();
```

Comment: I already have that in the code, not helpful sorry